# Have I used too many commas for this sentence?

Tags: grammar, commas

Here is what we are trying to say:

> Before you hit any of the URLs below, please, make sure you have logged into the application first using your default browser.

Are the commas correctly placed?  How else would you fix this sentence?

Comment: The more I think about it, could using both one comma or two commas be correct?  Depending on if it were spoken or not?  So if I pause after "please" then a comma would be needed then right?

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest

> Before you hit any of the URLs below, please make sure you have first logged into the application using your default browser.

[Note the shift in the placement of *first*, for clarity.]

Answer (score 1):

> Before you hit any of the URLs below, please, make sure you have logged into the application first using your default browser.

I think it would be just fine if it were:

> Before you hit any of the URLs below, please make sure you have logged into the application first using your default browser.

Pretty much, just get rid of the second comma, I don't believe that it is necessary.

EDIT:

To answer your commented question, yes, you can use a second comma. (Was just stating it wasn't necessary, not that you couldn't use it.)

Comment: I don't see why you find it necessary to tag in 'using your default browser'. Assuming this is on a webpage, they would already be using their default browser, yeah?

Comment: @Souta no, this would come to them via email.

Comment: @tchrist I do see that, but the last sentence was based off of my speech. As you can see, though, my response and correction to the question is all that matters. ;)

Comment: @cbmeeks Okay, but yeah, just take out the second comma and then you're good!

Comment: @cbmeeks I updated my answer to suit your second question